# Locking data to an Excel Chart

Tags: vba, charts, excel, excel-2007

In VBA code I create a chart from a sheet with filtered data.

When I go to create the second chart (re-filtering the data, creating new chart), both charts take the values of the second chart.

How can I **lock** the chart data of the first chart to prevent it from being overwritten when the second chart is created?

```
VBA code
1. Filter data for graph 1
2. Create graph 1
3. Filter data for graph 2
4. Create graph 2
Graph 1 and graph 2 now both have graph 2's data.
```

Now what I tried to do was to

```
5. Cut the chart and using "PasteSpecial" as an image.
   Sheets("Sheet2").PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

It worked on my computer but whenever it was run anywhere else it would produce an error.

Namaste

Comment: You can do it manually. 1) Click the data series. 2) In the formula bar click and press `F9`

Comment: That would be a great solution, except that @ulvund is doing this in VBA.

Comment: Since you didn't provide any code, it is probably best to send you to Jon Peltier's post about the Series formula:http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/change-series-formula-improved-routines/

Comment: Posting your current code would be a good start.

Comment: Sorry @Tim Mayes that was not relevant

Comment: Hello @brettdj I only have access to Mac Excel 2008 which does not support macros but you should be able to quickly  get the gist of the problem from the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the behavior you are looking for is to add code to your chart creation method to move the chart's source data to a hidden utility spreadsheet, or something similar, and not reference the "working" range directly.

For example, first copy the data to a hidden spreadsheet you create called "ChartData" and then change the chart creation code to look at that sheet instead of where it is looking now.  Then, you can either retain a counter on some configuration sheet, or use the spreadsheets shapes collection (search `ActiveSheet.Shapes` for objects of type `Chart`) to determine how many charts have already been created and set up subsequent charts to reference their own individual columns on "ChartData" so that there will be no overlap.

If you use the shapes collection, however, remember to cleanup the ChartData sheet to keep your data and chart collection in sync.

However you solve the problem though, the key is to have the charts reference their own data series and not a shared source.

Comment: Then for 40 graphs I will need 40 hidden spreadsheets, is that really the best way. There must be some way to 'consolidate' or lock the data points. One way I found was to paste it as an image, but that didn't transfer well to my colleague's computer.

Comment: No, for 40 graphs, you would need 40 columns on 1 hidden spreadsheet.  Alternatively, if your data is in rows, you would need 40 rows on 1 hidden spreadsheet.  No need to waste another entire spreadsheet for one data set.

Answer (score 3):

ulvund: Instead of manually copying and pasting it as an image, have you considered exporting the chart as an image and then re-importing it in Excel? The below works for me :)

Example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim FileNM As String

    FileNM = "C:\Sample.jpg"

    '~~> Export the chart as a jpg
    Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export Filename:=FileNM, FilterName:="jpg"

    DoEvents

    '~~> Import the saved image in Sheet 2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Pictures.Insert FileNM
End Sub
```

Comment: I never manually copy pasted anything. This was VBA code, using PasteSpecial. I will try your trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the first chart, you can do the following to convert its data from cell values to arrays. If you have too many data points, this will break.

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    ' must repeat for all series in the chart
    .Name = .Name
    .Values = .Values
    .XValues = .XValues
End With
```

For more details (especially how to make it accept more points before it breaks), check out [Delink Chart Data](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/DelinkChartData.html) on my web site